# onchange event in dijit.editor created programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am creating dojo widget programmatically, a dijit.editor, and adding a onchange event to copy the content of this widget to a hidden field.

The code is more or less this:

```
<div id="myEditor" onchange="myFunction()"></div>

<script>
    dojo.require("dijit.Editor");

    dojo.ready(function(){
         new dijit.Editor({
         height: "60px",
         plugins: []
        }, "myEditor");
    });
</script>
```

But the problem is that onchange event is never triggered, so myFunction is never called and the hidden field is never updated.

MY question for you guys is if creating programmatically a widget like this, needs another way to add the onchange or any other event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<script>
    dojo.require("dijit.Editor");

    dojo.ready(function () {
        var myEditor = new dijit.Editor({
            height: "60px",
            plugins: [],
            onChange: function () {
                alert("Hooray it worked!");
            }
        }, "myEditor");
    });
</script>



<div id="myEditor"></div>
```

Make sure the camel-case capitalization of onChange is correct.

EDIT:  Here's a declarative example in case you were missing one or more of these ideas, but it seems as though you were going the programmatic route so maybe stick with the first example if it suits you:

```
<script>
    dojo.require("dijit.Editor");

    dojo.ready(function () {
        dojo.parser.parse();
    });
</script>


<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Editor" id="myEditor" 
    data-dojo-props="onChange:function(){alert('It worked!');}">
</div>
```

Comment: Just to add some info, your declarative example will only work coçrrectly with dojo 1.7.0+
But the guy has not precised what version he was using...

Comment: Thanks, both examples worked fine. However the onChange event is called only when this editor lost focus, is there any other event that could be called just as editor'text was changed?

Comment: BTW I am using the google libraries for dojo, I think it is 1.6v

Comment: I just found the event onKeyUp, it works in the way I want to